# Why cab I not see my widget on simulator?

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

Flutter: 1.22

OS:Catalina 10.15.7

 Android Studio 4.1.0

I've created some code but everything doesn't appear.
I'm running this in a iPhone 11Pro simulator.

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: 100.0,
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 50.0, 20.0),
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text('Hello, hey, greetings, good day'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result: [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue with Flutter on Master channel.
The team is currently investigating and working on a fix.

Edit: This is only happening on iOS simulators, so until it gets fixed you need to use an Android emulator or a Physical iPhone.

You can follow up on [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68399) for more information and to get notified when the fix lands on Master channel.

Comment: Thank you so much Pedro, much appreciated!